# Re-prompt for restart with scheduled installations wording unclear

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

Logged onto our live server and it has the annoying prompt for a restart box.

This is really annoying as it's our production server.

I've read that I can alter the setting "Re-prompt for restart with scheduled installations" to change the time to 24 hours which would be less annoying.

However the wording is really unclear:

[image: Reprompt Image]

The first paragraph suggests I can change the value to 1440 and be nagged once per day.

But the second sentence suggests that if I change it, after it elapses the PC will simply restart itself.

If that happens I need to start looking for a new job. So I'm just looking to clarify if what will actually happen is, it will re-prompt after that time.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should take more control of the update process. You do know that you can control the downloading and installing of updates, right?

Comment: According to http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/00ddbf79-1afe-4715-b3c8-0ed274b0acd2/reprompt-for-restart-with-scheduled-installations-with-windows7-broken?forum=winserverwsus changing the value to any other than the 3 default settings doesn't have the desired effect anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It'll nag you no matter what. The best thing to do in this case is to stop and disable the Windows Update service. Once stopped, the prompt will stop appearing. Of course, you'll want to *eventually* turn this back on and restart the server.

In the future, set your updates to prompt on install instead of doing it on its own.